# dynamoDB - Get multiple items from DB by array of primary keys

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have an array of users id's and I want to get all users with that id from the dynamoDB table

Didn't find it in the documentation

any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

I ended up using batchGet, an operation of [AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html)

There's no support for multiple items with same key, so I have to define the key over and over again like this:

```
var dynamoConfig = {
  sessionToken:    process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
  region:          process.env.AWS_REGION
};
var dynamodbDocClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(dynamoConfig);

var params = {
  RequestItems: {
    tableName: {
      Keys: [
        {
          id: 'user1Id'
        },
        {
          id: 'user2Id'
        },
        {
          id: 'user3Id'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

dynamodbDocClient.batchGet(paramsForQueringFormerEvaluators, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('createEvaluation: get former evaluators: err: ', err);
    return;
  }

  var users = data.Responses.tableName;
  console.log('createEvaluation: get former evaluators: ', users);

});
```

Comment: what is paramsForQueringFormerEvaluators in your case? params?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the BatchGetItem API for this.

Of course, I can't help you with any code snippet without knowing your table schema. But you can look at the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use [`Scan`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Scan) method.

I'm currently using python [`boto3`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package. [Ref to `scan` in boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan). So the code would be like:

```
table = boto3.resourse('dynamodb').Table('users-table-name')
response = table.scan(
    ScanFilter={'user-id': {
        'AttributeValueList': user_ids,
        'ComparisonOperator': 'IN' }
    }
)
```

But i'm not sure what is better, using `BatchGetItem` or `Scan`. Probably it depends on two factors:

1. how many records in table (`table.item_count`)
2. how many items you need to get (`count(user_ids)`)

If `count(user_ids) << table.item_count` then you definitely need to use `BatchGetItem`.

If `count(user_ids) / table.item_count -> 1` then you need to use `Scan`.

Comment: Avoid scan operations if you know the items id's you're looking for. They're expensive to execute because the full data set - potentially across partitions - has to be scanned.

Comment: This can absolutely destroy you. Never use scan in a prod environment unless you have a very small table

Comment: Really bad idea, avoid use scan unless you don't known the PK. And if you don't known the PK, try to refactor your table to avoid scan!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function that converts a list of IDs into a list of documents using `batchGet`:

```js
async function getDocs(ids, docClient, tableName, key='id') {
  const getParams = {
    RequestItems: {
      [tableName]: {
        Keys: ids.map(id => ({[key]: id}))
      }
    }
  }
  return (await docClient.batchGet(getParams).promise()).Responses[tableName];
}
```